# TimeZone.setRawOffset like function in JSR310?

Tags: java

I'm new to JSR310. I'm using Calendar and TimeZone to calculate custom timezone via setting rawoffset of TimeZone class.

I want to use specific Timezone(America/New_York) rules but with custom offset.

And now I have to use JSR310 because of multi threading problem, I cannot find method like `TimeZone.setRawOffset()` in `JSR310`.

Is there any function like `TimeZone.setRawOffset()` in `JSR310`?

Or how can I get custom offset of the specific timezone (or ZoneId?) in JSR310?

Comment: You can take a look at [ZonedDateTime][1] and [OffsetDateTime][2]. 


  [1]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html
  [2]: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html

Comment: Thank you Pallavi. But I need this functionality,  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setRawOffset(int)  "If an underlying TimeZone implementation subclass supports historical GMT offset changes, the specified GMT offset is set as the latest GMT offset and the difference from the known latest GMT offset value is used to adjust all historical GMT offset values."

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve. To what extent do you want your time zone to look like America/New_York? Why are you setting a custom offset to start with?

Comment: Because I want a virtual timezone that starts a day at 17:00EST(EDT) which is the time of New York markets closes. In other words, virtual timezone UTC+2(3) but with "America/New_York" DaylightSavings transition rule. And it makes other part of my programming much easier.